# mb_detect_encoding always true

Tags: php, encoding

```
$title = òàè;
echo mb_detect_encoding($title,'UTF-8',true);
```

returns UTF-8

```
$title = òàè;
echo mb_detect_encoding($title,'ISO-8859-1',true);
```

returns ISO-8859-1

Why? It can't be both.

Comment: It is possible: [Check this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52cb68b125990c036fcd172ac186ee6add2e1a83) There are 6 bytes, presumably 3 ASCII characters and 3 diacritics in ISO-8859-1. It is possible that ISO-8859-1 uses the same character pair to create that character than UTF-8 uses to create the character itself, you need to look it up though.